# Convert from sql to linq query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I just wanted to convert following query to `LINQ` expression.

```
Select * 
from customer 
where customer_id in
    (select customer_id from cust where username=name)
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Which part are you stuck on

Comment: Do you use NHibernate, Entity Framework, DataSets, ...?

Comment: At what stage in development are you, do you have an ORM, or you even using a database, have you got anything working, or is this just a what if question

Comment: I have used entity framework in my application.

Comment: Getting the customer_ids from the cust table (`IEnumerable<int> customerIDs = cust.Where(x => x.username == name)`) and then `customer.Where(x => customerIDs.Contains(x.customer_id))` should translate to an IN clause. But why do you have 2 different customer tables?

Comment: @Dip you got two differents tables? and try get id from first where second table contains this id?

Comment: Actually in cust table there are two field and using Username I want to extract customer_id and using that customer_id I want all customer details.

Comment: @Dip, does that mean that the customer details do not include its `username`?

Comment: No its different.

Comment: @Dip looks like vc74 solve your problem, didn't he?

Answer (score 2):

So you have two tables: a `Cust` table and a `Customer` table. Both tables have a property `CustomerId`. The `Cust` table also has a property `UserName`.

Now given a string variable `name`, you want all elements from the `Customers` table that have a `CustomerId` equal to the `CustomerId` of all elements from the `Cust` table that have a `UserName` equal to `name`.

Seems like a Join to me:

```
var result = myDbContext.Cust             // take the cust table
    .Where(cust => cust.UserName == name) // keep only custs with Username == name
    .Join(myDbContext.Customers,          // Join the result with Customers table
    cust => cust.CustomerId,              // From every cust take the CustomerId
    customer => customer.CustomerId,      // From every customer take the CustomerId
    (cust, customer) =>                   // when they match take the cust and the Customer
       customer                           // to select the matching Customer
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to customer table in `dbcontext.customer` and to cust table in `dbcontext.cust`

```
var name = "desired username"
var result = dbcontext.customer.Where(customer => dbcontext.cust.Where(cust => cust.username == name).Select(cust => cust.customer_id).Any(cust => cust == customer.customer_id)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it for my application.

Comment: Its not working because tables are in different context.

Comment: @Dip it makes no difference if they are in a different context, you could replace `dbcontext.cust` with any other collection including the other context.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one;

```
var custList = ctx.Customer.Where(x=>x.username==name).ToList();

var finalList=ctx.Customer.ToList().Where(x=>custList.Select(x=>x.customer_id).ToList().Contains(x.customer_id))
```